# How do I make one cell correspond with another for google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

```
    A      B       C        D   
1|Male  |  5   |Male avg|   8   |
2|Female|  4   |        |       |
3|Female|  8   |        |       |
4|Male  |  9   |        |       |
5|Male  |  10  |        |       |
```

How do I make it so that google spreadsheets sums the cells that are beside a cell with "male" then takes a average out of 10? If possible, I would like an answer where the values change automatically when I fill in a new row.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want it to sum all cell with *Male* next to them and then divide by 10?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
=averageif(A:A,"Male",B:B)
```